# Microsoft Sync Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, microsoft-sync-framework

I have been working through some of the sync framework demos and one thing that doesn't seem to be clear is what you have to do to add a table? So if I start with Order and Order Details in my demo and I want to add a third table what are the steps? I have tried a few things, but they don't seem to be working.  It appears that I would also have to modify the actual scope xml in my scope config table.  Is that correct?

So basically what is best practice for handling changes to the master / source schema? Do you have to manually update the clients or will the changes made to the master / source be propogated down to the clients like with the initial sync?

Any info would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

S

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sync Fx out of the box doesnt support changing the scope definition (add/remove column, add/remove table, add/remove filter).

the fastest workaround is to deprovision and reprovision the scope with a new definition.

or as you mentioned, you can hack your way to the sync fx objects. check [http://jtabadero.wordpress.com/2011/03/24/modifying-sync-framework-scope-definition-part-2-workarounds](http://jtabadero.wordpress.com/2011/03/24/modifying-sync-framework-scope-definition-part-2-workarounds/)/

Answer (score 1):

I would version the scope definitions by including a version number in their names. Explicitly include column names in the scopes so you remain backward compatible.
Deploy a new version of the client with the new scope version, it will sync with the corresponding scope on the server.
Assuming you use WCF or some other mechanism to sync remotely, you can dispatch the incoming sync request to the correct server sync provider based on the scope name.

Comment: sometimes. You need to make sure that you sync tables in the correct order within the same scope. I've read other solutions like removing the FKs on the client before sync and adding them back in after, but I'm not a fan of that. Another, less dirty, hack is to check for this type of error during sync (FK violations) and resync until those errors are gone, but fixing the table order in a scope and maybe even subdividing into separate scopes is better imo.